# What does C++ language definition say about the extent of the static keyword?

Tags: c++, syntax, static, language-lawyer, grammar

In C++, if I have a class:

```
class Example {
  static int s_One, s_Two;

  ...
};
```

Does the language clearly define that `s_Two` is also static?

In other words, does the `static` keyword extent go everywhere the `int` goes, or can it be like `*` and only apply to one variable?

Comment: This question can be answered by reading [the standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/). But, why don't you simply remove the ambiguity by declaring each variable on its own?

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Arguably, most answers about C++ can be answered by reading the standard. But the standard is big and sometimes difficult to navigate.

Comment: @JesperJuhl The answer might also be valuable to other people.

Comment: it would be pretty stupid to not apply all the declarators to all the variables introduced by the declaration... "C++: hold my beer `int* a, b`"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, it applies to every name in that declaration:

> [`[dcl.stc]/1:`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec#dcl.stc-1) *[..]* At most one *storage-class-specifier* shall appear in a given *decl-specifier-seq* *[..]* The *storage-class-specifier* applies to the name declared by each *init-declarator* in the list *[..]*

Answer (score 2):

According to the C++ 17 Standard (10 Declarations)

2 A simple-declaration or nodeclspec-function-declaration of the form

```
attribute-specifier-seqopt decl-specifier-seqopt init-declarator-listopt ;
```

And (10.1 Specifiers):

> 1 The specifiers that can be used in a declaration are

```
decl-specifier:
    storage-class-specifier
    ...
```

So in this declaration

```
static int s_One, s_Two;
```

the `decl-specifier-seq` contains two `decl-specifiers`, `static` (storage class specifier) and `int`. Thus the storage class specifier `static` describes the both variables in the `init-declarator-list` `s_One` and `s_Two`.

Comment: That's not enough; this doesn't show that the SCS applies to both, just that is possible.

Comment: I'd still write `static int s_One; static int s_Two;`. Much more readable and unambiguous.

Comment: @JesperJuhl No, this is invalid C++ syntax.

Comment: No, it is not. Why do you say it is invalid?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow why?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow How is declaring two separate `static` `int`s invalid syntax?

Comment: @Doch88 I did not see that there is a semicolon instead of comma.:)

Comment: @Rakete1111 What is not enough for you?